# What Typescript definition should I use for a route link using Vue Router?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

Having trouble finding what TS interface I should use for route links.

I have a shared component in my Vue 3 + Typescript application that takes in internal and external links. Think of them as toast messages.

The HTML looks like this:

```
// v-for toast in toasts
{{ toast.message }}

<button
  class="my-button-class"
  tag="a"
  :to="toast.external_url">
{{ toast.call_to_action }}
</button>
```

This is what the Typescript definition for these toasts look like. You can pass in `internal_url` or `external_url`:

```
import type { RouteRecord } from 'vue-router';


export interface Toast {
  message: string;
  call_to_action: string;
  external_url?: string;
  interal_url?: RouteRecord; // RouteLocation, etc. doesn't work
}
```

**My problem is I can't find the exact TS definition I need to use for `internal_url`.**

`RouteRecord`, `RouteLocation`, etc. from the [Vue Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#Interfaces) do not work. A typical use of the toast messages would look like this:

```
addToast({
  message: 'Someone viewed your profile',
  call_to_action: 'Review',
  internal_url: { name: routeNames.profile, query: { id: current_user.id }} 
}
```

I was thinking [RouteLocation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/RouteLocation.html) is the perfect interface for this, but it's also not correct.

An example error from `RouteLocation`:

```
Type internal_url is missing the following properties from type 'RouteLocation': matched, fullPath, hash, redirectedFrom, and 3 more.
```

Comment: Try `RouteLocationRaw`?  But also, please explain what it means when an interface is "not correct".  Paste any warnings/errors you get as part of your question.  TS errors can give helpful information such as expected type vs. actual type

Comment: Ah you're right. Added an example error, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to navigate to a route using a name and possibly pass query parameters, you should indeed use the `RouteLocationRaw` interface as mentioned in the comment. However, it seems like you're using Vue Router in conjunction with TypeScript, and sometimes the type inference can be a bit tricky.

update your Toast interface to correctly define the `internal_url` property:

```
export interface Toast {
  message: string;
  call_to_action: string;
  external_url?: string;
  internal_url?: RouteLocationRaw;
}
```

Now you can use the `internal_url` property with the RouteLocationRaw type in your code:

```js
import { RouteLocationRaw } from 'vue-router';

// Define your route names
const routeNames = {
  profile: 'profile', // replace this with your actual route name
};

// Example usage
addToast({
  message: 'Someone viewed your profile',
  call_to_action: 'Review',
  internal_url: { name: routeNames.profile, query: { id: current_user.id }} 
});
```